# PHP MYSQL updating multiple rows using values from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, sql-update

I've working on this problem for a while, and I've been stuck for a few days.
What I have is a basic blog system, and right now I'm stuck on trying to delete/hide posts from a list.

```
if(isset($_POST['hideBtn']) && isset($_POST['hidePost'])){
   $checked = $_POST['hidePost'];
   print_r($checked);
} elseif(isset($_POST['hideBtn']) && !isset($_POST['hidePost'])){
   echo "Nothing Selected";
}
```

There is a checkbox for each post that shows up in the list.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hidePost[]" value="<?php echo $post_id;?>">
```

Now when I run the above script and check off post 10, 8 and 4 and press the "hideBtn" button I get:

> Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 8 [1] => 4 )

This is where I get stuck. I'm trying to take the values of this array and use them in a MSQL query to find the post_id's that I want to hide:

```
if(isset($_POST['hideBtn']) && isset($_POST['hidePost'])){
   $checked = $_POST['hidePost'];
   print_r($checked);
   $hide_post = 'UPDATE post SET hide_post=1 
                 WHERE post_id IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $checked)) . ')';
   $db->query($hide_post);
} elseif(isset($_POST['hideBtn']) && !isset($_POST['hidePost'])){
   echo "Nothing Selected";
}
```

This gives me the same result as before:

> Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 8 [1] => 4 )

and there's no change in the database.

Here's the database table, hide_post defaults to 0:

> post 
> post_id user_id title body hide_post

## EDIT

Alright it seems my issue was due to too many database queries on one connection.

This is what I have included at the top of my page:

```
<?php

//get record count
$record_count = $db->query("SELECT * FROM post");

//number of posts per page
$per_page = 4;
//number of pages
$pages = ceil($record_count->num_rows/$per_page);

//get page number
if(isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])){
    $page = $_GET['p'];
}else{
    $page = 1;
}

if($page<=0){
    $start = 0;
}else{
    $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
}

$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;

//get post information from database
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, LEFT(body, 100) AS body, posted, category, user_name FROM post
                        INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=post.category_id 
                        INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id=post.user_id
                        WHERE hide_post = 0
                        order by post_id desc limit $start, $per_page");

$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $posted, $category, $user_name);
?>
```

From what I've read about the error I was getting: `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` I think I need to use `mutli_query` or `$stmt->store_result()` but this is my first time using php and mysql and I have no idea how to go about it.

## EDIT 2

Alright, I found another way to fix it, all I did was move the query that hides the post to below the `while()` that runs the actual fetching of post information. I wish I realized this sooner heh.

Comment: Could you print `$hide_post` to see if the implode is done correctly?

Comment: Ensure your error reporting is on for SQL queries (using `mysql_error()` or `mysqli_error($link)`, a table name/the order might be incorrect.

Comment: the implode looks find to me, i checked post 9 and 7 and it gave me: `UPDATE post SET hide_post=1 WHERE post_id IN (9,7)`

Comment: @Titanium ok so when I run `$db->query($hide_post) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($db));` i get this on a blank page:`Could not connect: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Comment: @Brian - pleased you fixed it. If you solve it yourself, it's better to create your own answer and tick it - so it removes the question from the unanswered lists, and so the data API separates 'question' from 'answer' correctly. If you get a mo, you can use Rollback to do that on this question - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my problem was not caused by the query itself, but where I had placed it.

All I had to do to avoid the error: `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` was to take my second query that hides/deletes posts, that are selected by the user, and put the query after the `while()` loop that would `fetch()` each post.

Basically I was trying to make a second query before the first query was finished.

Answer (score -2):

Using this code

```
$checked = array ( 0 => 10, 1 => 8, 2 => 4 );
//print_r($checked);
$hide_post = 'UPDATE post SET hide_post=1 
WHERE post_id IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $checked)) . ')';

echo $hide_post;
```

your query becomes

```
UPDATE post SET hide_post=1 WHERE post_id IN (10,8,4)
```

Run the same query in `phpmyadmin` and check whether the same query returns ant error or not.

Comment: I ran UPDATE post SET hide_post=1 WHERE post_id IN (10,8,4)  in phpmyadmin and there were no errors

Comment: @BrianBaker Check your database connection and also check you included necessary database file in your php file

Comment: The db is included at the start of the file as $db. The posts are pulled from the database using the same connection, so I'd imagine updating the database would work as well.